# Python to Perl translator, python indentations

Tags: python, perl, perl-data-structures

I am translating Python to Perl for a project. I am asking for is a hint, or a starting point for my problem.

Problem: How should I go about translating multi-line `if`/`for`/`while` statements in Python (assuming indentation for one block is equivalent to 4 spaces for each) to Perl?

I am writing this in Perl, so I was thinking of using some sort of data structure (such as an array) to capture a block of consecutive lines having the same level of indentation, but I am not sure exactly how i go about doing this?

Another possible way could be to "peek" at the next line (I am reading the Python file using `while (<>)`) however that changes the pointer to next line.

Here's an example Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

x = 4
for i in range(0, x+1):
    print i
    i = i + 1
```

Hopefully translated to:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$x = 4;
foreach $i (0..$x) {
    print $i, "\n";
    $i = $i + 1;
}
```

Comment: You probably just need to keep track of the fact that you are inside a block, so when the indentation changes you can emit your closing brace }

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why anyone would want to do this but apparently there is a project called [Perthon](http://perthon.sourceforge.net/) which claims to translate Python into Perl.

At least they are doing it the right way by using [Parse::RecDescent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Parse%3a%3aRecDescent) instead of using regular expressions ;-)